# identify button is not visible while spying objects in blue prism

Tags: button, visible, identify, blueprism

While spying objects in blueprism using application modeller, i am not able to see identify button, instead just seeing only launch option.

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Answer (score 3):

It's because the application that you are tring to spy on, isn't launched.

You need to launch it first(from BP)and then Blue Prism alow you to spy on it. If you open aplication "on your own" BP wont see it.

Answer (score 1):

In Win 10, some applications like calculator cannot be spyed as in Win 7. 
In order to get identify button you need to do belows:

1. Launch the application in an object using Navigate stage. 
   For example, you can create an object with the name "Launch".
2. Attach the application. You need to create another object using Navigate stage with the name "Attach".
3. Then you need to use Page stage referencing "Attach" page after Launch stage.

When you complete above, please run it and then, click on the Application Modeler. You can be able to use Identify button at that time.

[My blue prism object screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgH14.png)

Comment: Hi Sinem, thanks for your answer! As links can become broken, could you include some of the relevant code as a `formatted code block` in the answer?

Comment: Hi Brydenr, thanks for your reply. I only shared my object studio screenshot, I didn't share code block.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly reconfigure the application in application modeller, while doing so, give attention to the options you select in application modeller. Setting the correct options like web based or windows based application the problem will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Can be two reasons:

1. Either your application is not launched properly.
2. Sometimes we face problems with some versions of applications.

The best way to fix your problem is

- Edit your settings remove the application path from the navigate stage.
- Launch the application separately
- Open Navigate stage > Action > Attach
- Provide the window title within quotes (example: "Calculator")
- Click OK then run the object
- Now if you go to application modeller
- You will be able to see the identify button under the element.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

"Microsoft.WindowsCalculator" use in the application executable  path in application modeller.put Microsoft.WindowsCalculator in between <  >